# How do I change the combobox icon in fluent-ui select field?

Tags: reactjs

I am using fluent-ui. I want to change the given Combobox icon to a different font icon. How to achieve this?

link: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/combobox

Thanks so much